# Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver even when the extensions are there

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

Another one for this error that is driving me nuts.
I've read literally 50 posts in stackoverflow and tried all different solutions:

- Checking php.ini to see if the extensions are enabled and the folder to check if the dll's are present

[image: Enabled and extension_dir pointing to the correct dir too]

[image: Present in phpinfo()]

[image: Files present in xampp/php/ext]

- Also tried extracting a php_pdo_mysql.dll file from the latest php version, checking if maybe the xampp original file was broken or corrupted with no luck.
- Setting the path in environment variables

This is what I'm using for my local environment:

- Xampp 7.2.4
- PHP 7.2.4
- Apache 2.4.33

And this is my code:

```
return new PDO('
    mysql:host='.Env::getInstance()->env('dbhost').';
    dbname='.Env::getInstance()->env('dbname'),
    Env::getInstance()->env('dbusername'),
    Env::getInstance()->env('dbpassword')
);
```

Is there something I haven't tried? please I want to fix this issue for once and for all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Env`? I assume you are using MySQL?

Comment: @adam yes. MySQL and env is a custom class to bring my config variables, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed to the PDO constructor must be like $dsn in the example of the php manual below.

```
<?php
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

It looks like your first argument has the wrong content.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, silly me for trying to make it look pretty. thanks a lot